# Is there any other way to use css file under <noscript> tag in html 4.01?

Tags: html, w3c-validation, html4

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>


<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/css/reset.css" media="screen">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/css/text.css" media="screen">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/css/960.css" media="screen">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/css/fedora960.css" media="screen">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/css/fedora960-lang.css" media="screen">
    <!-- legacy -->
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/static/images/favicon.ico" type="image/vnd.microsoft.icon">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="print" href="/static/css/print.css">
    <!--[if IE 7]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="${path}/static/css/ie7.css" media="screen" />
    <style type="text/css">
        #wrapper
        {
            height: 100%;
            overflow: visible!important;
        }
            .downloadsidebar a {
            backgroundimage: none!important;
        }
    </style>

    <![endif]-->

<title>Fedora Project Homepage</title>
</head>
<body id="fedoraproject-org" class="lang-en">
    <noscript>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="/static/css/nojs.css">
    </noscript>
...
...
</body>
</html>
```

But this code raises error while checking with w3c validator that `<link>` tag is not allowed under `<body>` tag in html 4.01. 
As if `<link>` tag is used under `<noscript>` tag under `<head>` tag in html5. It gives no error.
But I want to know any other possible way to use css file under `<noscript>` tag in html 4.01. Please give some ideas.

Comment: Why must you use an HTML 4 doctype?

Comment: You can use `link` in the `head` and combine `noscript` selector to the selectors in the css file

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no way to use a `link` tag inside a `noscript` tag that validates for HTML 4.

The `noscript` tag is only allowed in the `body` tag in HTML 4, and the `link` tag is only allowed in the `head` tag.

[HTML 4 spec: noscript](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/scripts.html#h-18.3.1)
[MDN: <link> element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/link)